# Explanation on one of my questions which got closed because of a given reason

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I had asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71892768/how-to-use-b-with-fmt-println) question yesterday which was answered. However, this morning, the question was closed citing the reason: *This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.*

Similar questions on this site which have been asked before and answered as well as not closed and mostly well received:

1. [String formatting: % vs. .format vs. f-string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/string-formatting-vs-format-vs-f-string-literal)
2. [Python Terminal Text Output Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36799168/python-terminal-text-output-formatting)
3. [print!() formatting for strings with terminal escape codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69606485/print-formatting-for-strings-with-terminal-escape-codes)
4. [Format a Go string without printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123865/format-a-go-string-without-printing)

I think that my question fits well along these lines. Why then is it not considered a programming question?

Answer (score 7):

To be honest I don’t remember exactly which close reason I used. <strike>Definitely not “Typo” And probably not “About general computing”, since that would be just incorrect. In case I was the one choosing “About general compiting”, that would be a mistake on my part.</strike> Edit: Ironically, I was the one closing as "Typo", which may have some merits, but in this case it was surely a worse close reason.

Regardless, the question closure was warranted as “Needs debugging details” because it was missing a critical debugging detail, i.e. *in what environment you were running that code*.

Since the escape sequence `\b` renders on a terminal, running the code on the Go playground already explains your expected vs. actual output, but this was left for readers to guess.

Even if an educated guess *can* be made, that doesn’t diminish the fact that it is a guess.

As a matter of fact, there is a deleted answer to your question which was just tricked into providing an unapplicable explanation because you weren’t clear enough in your problem statement. Unfortunately that poster deleted their own answer probably before you could see it, otherwise the comments under it might have given you some hints about how to fix your question.

With that said it could be still argued that expecting the backspace character to render in a non-terminal output could be considered a “Typo”, although I wouldn’t normally close all questions like this one as “Typo”. I should have chosen "Needs debugging details", for the reasons mentioned above. **Edit:** now that I'm trying to remember, I probably chose "Typo" not because it was a typo but because it was "Not reproducible", due to not knowing *where* to reproduce the issue. Still a worse close reason than "Needs debugging details".

Anyway, now that the missing information was edited into the question and the title properly fixed, the question is reopened and answered. But please, consider that **you** should be the one editing the missing information in, whenever possible.

With that said, the “not about programming” banner you saw on your question is shown when the close voters disagree about the close reason. In other words, when three different close reasons were given. That is indeed unfortunate and somewhat unhelpful because your question **is** about programming; however the focus of that close message is not *only* on the first sentence. You have to read it together with the second one:

> This question does not appear to be about **programming within the scope defined in the help center**.

This message essentially means “your question doesn’t fit Stack Overflow guidelines” which is the only reasonable statement that the system can provide when all the close reasons are different.

Comment: Maybe the system should show EACH of the close reasons rather than trying to summarize in one line.  At least then the OP would know what REALLY happened rather than leading them to have to guess.  You say a question isn't perfect if readers might have to guess, then why is SO making the OP guess about the close reasons.  In fact, hiding that info when all the close voters don't agree is very, very clearly NOT helpful at all.

Comment: @jfriend00 I totally agree, the current close reasons and banners have several shortcomings that frequently make it harder on the OP to figure out what’s going on and take appropriate measure. At times when I vote to close I also leave a comment to provide some guidance, but I don’t always have the bandwidth to do that on each and every question. In this particular case I should have posted a comment, because the close banner alone is unhelpful

Comment: If the reason for my close vote is not already explained in a comment by someone else, I will leave a comment.  I consider it my obligation to explain why I'm voting to close.   I think we owe that to the community here, particularly to new users.  I know there are lots of drive-by close voters that never or rarely do that.  I think that's a disservice.  I liken it to sending a child to the corner for misbehaving, but not telling them what they did wrong.  It punishes them, but doesn't educate them which does nothing in the short or long run, but make them mad.

Comment: I personally think the interface for voting to close for any reason other than a duplicate, should require an explanation from the close voter and that should be visible to the OP, particularly when there are multiple different reasons. It should be part of the deal with a close vote that you educate the OP on why.  It takes, but 15 seconds to type one or two lines to explain.  IMO, it's more important to educate posters on why their post is inappropriate than it is to save a few seconds for a close voter.

Comment: So, how do we get StackExchange to change the close banner so that it always includes ALL the close reasons?

Comment: @jfriend00 You post a feature request. But I am pretty sure it already exists.

Comment: @ModusTollens - If you can find one that already exists, please link it.  In my search (not really sure what to search for because people may call it something different), I couldn't find it.

Comment: @jfriend00 A bit busy right now, sorry. I remember it being discussed, could also have been on meta.stackexchange.com. Or ask a new one, it will be linked to a dupe if it already exists.

Comment: screenshot of your vote to help you remember https://i.stack.imgur.com/TleAD.png

Comment: Hey, may I raise it instead?

Comment: @jfriend00 Maybe [Distinguish close votes by reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54917/distinguish-close-votes-by-reason) from 12 years ago.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - Yeah that is one.  But, Apparently that feature request didn't do any good, nor I assume will my upvoting it.  12 years ago and 334 upvotes and the feature still works the same way it did back then.  It appears there's not much point in posting feature requests like that.